# How to design PI controller for the field weakening control of the three phase induction motor?

Tags: control, control-system, induction-motor, pid-controller, vector-control

In the book called *Electric Motor Control* in the *Chapter 8* I have found following field weakening strategy for the three phase induction motor

[image]

The aforementioned field weakening strategy is based on the PI controller of the stator voltage. My goal is to theoretically design the PI controller gains. For this task I need to have a transfer function of the plant i.e. transfer function between the stator voltage magnitude and d-component of the stator current.

I have attempted to derive the differential equation describing the dynamic between the stator voltage and d-component of the stator current from the basic voltage equations of the three phase induction motor expressed in the stationary reference frame

$$
\hat{v}_s = R_s\cdot\hat{i}_s + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\hat{\psi_s} \\
\hat{v}_r = R_r\cdot\hat{i}_r + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\hat{\psi_r} + j\cdot\omega_m\cdot p_p\cdot\hat{\psi_r} = 0 \\
\hat{\psi}_s = L_s\cdot\hat{i}_s + L_m\cdot\hat{i}_r \\
\hat{\psi}_r = L_r\cdot\hat{i}_r + L_m\cdot\hat{i}_s \\
$$

and I have stuck at this point.

So my question is how to derive the differential equation describing the dynamic between the stator voltage and d-component of the stator current from the basic voltage equations respectively how to design the gains of the PI controller for the field weakening control? Maybe some guideline for the PI controller design would be sufficient.

**EDIT**:

I have found another book called: *Control of Electric Machine Drives Systems*. Here in *Chapter 5* is written: *"the gain setting of the flux weakening controller is not straightforward and the gains should be set by trial and error. The bandwidth of the flux weakening control loop should be low enough to prevent the interference with the current control loop."*